# How do you make a button that formats a transaction MetaMask can use?

Tags: web3js

So far, after many hours of searching, it is not documented or shown in any tutorial a single working example. I tried this:

```
function BuyButton() {
        web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, result) {
            web3.eth.sendTransaction(
                {from:result[0],
                to:"0x23db62344f40fc356sfcba267514270e60eed82fd",
                value:  1000000000000000000,
                gas:  300000,
                data:   {"constant": false,
                        "inputs": [],
                        "name": "BuyItem",
                        "outputs": [],
                        "payable": true,
                        "stateMutability": "payable",
                        "type": "function"},
                    }, function(err, transactionHash) {
              if (!err)
                console.log(transactionHash); 
            });
        });   
    }
```

But it doesn't work. I can get MetaMask to generate a simple send without the data field, but there is no documentation in web3.js exactly how to use that data field, nor are there examples of someone making something as simple as a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions I'm making:

- You're using web3.js 0.2x.x.
- `0x23db62344f40fc356sfcba267514270e60eed82fd` is a contract.
- The object you're trying to pass as `data` is part of that contract's ABI.

If those assumptions are true, I believe the following will work:

```
var abi = [{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "BuyItem",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": true,
    "stateMutability": "payable",
    "type": "function",
}];

var address = '0x23db62344f40fc356sfcba267514270e60eed82fd';

var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address);

web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, result) {
    contract.BuyItem({
        from: result[0],
        value: web3.fromWei(1, 'ether'),
    }, function (err, transactionHash) {
        console.log(err, transactionHash);
    });
});
```

I wrote a blog post last month that goes over the basics of writing a DApp: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/13/building-decentralized-apps-with-ethereum-and-javascript/.

Comment: The problem is the parameter data is just defined in the docs, there is no examples or syntax for using it. Someone on gitter just gave me a working answer, though I don't understand why it works.

Comment: Did my code not work for you? Or are you trying to manually construct `data`?

Comment: I posted answer below just now. :-) I was trying to manually construct too with a field. You can buy and sell on MetaMask with Ropsten here: http://kekdirect.com/blockchainart/index.html

The sell button has a fixed value for now. I'm sorting bug of web3.js that allows rounded numbers, and MM is complicit in displaying the incorrect price for things with zeros until the sixth decimal place.

Comment: Yeah, your answer looks pretty much like mine. To pass arguments, just put them before the transaction object. The documentation is here: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods.

Comment: BTW, for your rounding thing: `web3.toBigNumber('1000010000000000007').div(1000000000000000000).toString()` will give you a full-precision number to display, though yes, I see that MetaMask truncates. (I think that's fine, since the amount it cuts off is never more than a tenth of a penny at today's ether prices.)

Comment: Thanks for this tip! A tenth of a penny obfuscated on heavy volume will be a lot. In the drug world that crypto is based on, people have died for trying to short a few bucks. It doesn't follow the logic behind not having decimals in Solidity either. Floating point numbers are not good for finance. In this case, Solidity does it right, and makes a potential accounting nightmare just an obfuscation that can be corrected.

Comment: It takes on average 12.5 seconds or so to mine a block. During that time, the price of ether certainly fluctuates more than a tenth of a penny. I'm not sure how volume could be a problem... someone paying this lots of times would be paying transaction fees each time, which far exceed tenths of pennies.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Contract = ContractName.at("0x23db62344f40fc356sfcba267514270e60eed82fd")

$("#BuyButton").click(function(){

                Contract.BuyFunction(
                {from: web3.eth.defaultAccount,
                to:"0x23db62344f40fc356sfcba267514270e60eed82fd",
                value:  Price,
                gas:  300000
                    }, function(err, transactionHash) {
              if (!err)
                console.log(transactionHash); 
            })});
```

It's a jQuery triggered button. I'm still trying to figure out how to correctly pass data to a function with an expected argument. It looks like this:

```
$("#SellButton").click(function(){

    Contract.SellandSetPriceFunction(

               "PassedValue",

                    {from: web3.eth.defaultAccount,
                    to:"0x23db62344f40fc356sfcba267514270e60eed82fd",
                    value:  0,
                    gas:  300000
                        }, function(err, transactionHash) {
                  if (!err)
                    console.log(transactionHash); 
                })});
```